# Unexpected as.POSIXct and strptime Behavior around DST

Tags: r, posixct, strptime

I'm experiencing strange behavior with `as.POSIXct()`. I have data collected this year and I'm trying to deal with the DST change on November 4th. I'm in `CST6CDT` or `"America/Chicago"`. My date data is a character vector that looks like the following:

```
"11/04/2018 1:59 AM"
"11/04/2018 2:00 AM"
"11/04/2018 2:01 AM"
...
"11/11/2018 3:52 PM"
"11/11/2018 2:55 PM"
```

I set my data logger to log the data in UTC thinking I'd save myself DST hassle later on. Unfortunately, the computer I use to download the data has its time set to `"America/Chicago"` so when it connected to my data logger it switched the time back an hour (hence the switch from 3:52 PM to 2:55 PM).

So, I fixed the date issue so that it looks like the following:

```
"11/04/2018 1:59 AM"
"11/04/2018 1:00 AM"
"11/04/2018 1:01 AM"
...
"11/11/2018 2:52 PM"
"11/11/2018 2:55 PM"
```

However, when I use `as.POSIXct()` to change these dates its doing so in a strange way. E.g.

```
as.POSIXct("11/04/2018 1:30 AM","%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p",tz='CST6CDT')
"2018-11-04 01:30:00 CDT" 
as.POSIXct("11/04/2018 1:31 AM","%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p",tz='CST6CDT') 
"2018-11-04 01:31:00 CST"
```

I figure, okay, let me specify the system specific tz

```
as.POSIXct("11/04/2018 1:30 AM","%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p",tz=Sys.timezone())
"2018-11-04 01:30:00 CDT"
as.POSIXct("11/04/2018 1:31 AM","%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p",tz=Sys.timezone())
"2018-11-04 01:31:00 CST"
```

Maybe I need to explicitly let the system know that the 2 sequential times were in CDT

```
as.POSIXct("11/04/2018 1:30 AM CDT","%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p",tz=Sys.timezone()) 
"2018-11-04 01:30:00 CDT"
as.POSIXct("11/04/2018 1:31 AM CDT","%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p",tz=Sys.timezone()) 
"2018-11-04 01:31:00 CST"
```

And now I'm just thoroughly confused. I thought that `as.POSIXct()` automatically recognized DST and therefore would know that in `"America/Chicago"` DST was observed on November 4th shifting from CDT to CST at 2:00 AM. This issue also occurs in strptime:

```
strptime("11/04/2018 1:30 AM","%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
"2018-11-04 01:30:00 CDT"
strptime("11/04/2018 1:31 AM","%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
"2018-11-04 01:31:00 CST"
```

This is occurring both in the R version I was using: `R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) -- "Short Summer"` as well as the newest version of R: `R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"` and its occurring in both the 32 and 64 bit versions.

However,`seq.POSIXt(from=as.POSIXct("11/04/2018 1:00 AM","%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p", tz=Sys.timezone()), length.out=61, by='1 mins')` produces the expected:

```
 [1] "2018-11-04 01:00:00 CDT" "2018-11-04 01:01:00 CDT"
 [3] "2018-11-04 01:02:00 CDT" "2018-11-04 01:03:00 CDT"
 ...
[31] "2018-11-04 01:30:00 CDT" "2018-11-04 01:31:00 CDT"
...
[59] "2018-11-04 01:58:00 CDT" "2018-11-04 01:59:00 CDT"
[61] "2018-11-04 01:00:00 CST"
```

**tl/dr:** DST is causing me issues because as.POSIXct() is acting in a way that is unexpected. I've been looking at this issue over several days and I can't figure it out so any help would be greatly appreciated.